# How to draw circles around circular path with D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How to draw circles with random sizes around circular path with D3js, so that small circles will be randomly distributed and not overlapping one with each other.

Here is how it should look:

[image]

and here is what i was able to get

[image]

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var angle, offset, data,
        size         = [8, 15],
        width        = 500,
        color        = d3.scale.category10(),
        height       = 600,
        radius       = 200,
        dispersion   = 10,
        svgContainer = d3.select('body').append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

    data = d3.range(100).map(function () {
        angle  = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        offset = Math.max(size[0], size[1]) + radius + dispersion;
        return {
            cx : offset + Math.cos(angle) * radius + rand(-dispersion, dispersion),
            cy : offset + Math.sin(angle) * radius + rand(-dispersion, dispersion),
            r  : rand(size[0], size[1])
        };

    });

    svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr({
                r    : function (d) {return d.r},
                cx   : function (d) {return d.cx},
                cy   : function (d) {return d.cy},
                fill : function (d, i) {return color(i % 3)}
            });

    function rand(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb8bgcrn/1/

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Is there a way to display it with d3 force layout but without using links ?

Comment: Refer [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution in detecting collision function when generating random coordinates, here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrychuba/6r3rqj01/) and code:

```
    (function () {
    var angle, offset, data, x, y, r,
        collision, circle1, circle2,
        circles      = [],
        size    = [8, 15],
        width   = 500,
        color   = d3.scale.category10(),
        height  = 600,
        radius  = 130,
        dispersion = 10,
        svgContainer = d3.select('body').append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);


    function detectCollision(c2, c1) {
        var dx   = c1.cx - c2.cx;
        var dy   = c1.cy - c2.cy;
        var rSum = c1.r + c2.r;

        return ((Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2)) < Math.pow(rSum, 2));
    }

    var sh = 2, elements = 55;
    data = d3.range(elements).map(function (i) {
        do {
            // dispersion += i / 50;
            angle  = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            offset = Math.max(size[0], size[1]) + radius + dispersion + (elements/sh);

            x = offset + Math.cos(angle) * radius + rand(- (dispersion + i / sh), dispersion + i / sh);
            y = offset + Math.sin(angle) * radius + rand(- (dispersion + i / sh), dispersion + i / sh);
            r = rand(size[0], size[1]);

            circle2 = {cx : x, cy : y, r : r};

            collision = false;
            if (circles.length > 1) {
                circles.forEach(function (d) {
                    circle1 = {cx : d.cx, cy : d.cy, r : d.r};
                    if (detectCollision(circle1, circle2)) {
                        collision = true;
                    }
                });
            }

        } while (collision);

        circles.push(circle2);

        return circles[circles.length - 1];

    });

    svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")

        .attr({
            r    : function (d) {
                return d.r
            },
            cx : function (d) {
                return d.cx
            },
            cy : function (d) {
                return d.cy
            },
            fill : function (d, i) {
                return color(i % 3)
            }
        });

    function rand(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 7):

I have made some updates to your fiddle and applied collision detection as in the demo I mentioned in the comment. Hope this helps.

```js
var angle, offset, data,
  size = [8, 15],
  width = 500,
  color = d3.scale.category10(),
  height = 600,
  radius = 200,
  dispersion = 10,    
  svgContainer = d3.select('body').append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(0.05)
  .charge(function(d, i) {
    return i ? 0 : -2000;
  })
  .distance(500)
  .size([width, height]);

data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
  angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  offset = Math.max(size[0], size[1]) + radius + dispersion;
  return {
    x: offset + Math.cos(angle) * radius + rand(-dispersion, dispersion),
    y: offset + Math.sin(angle) * radius + rand(-dispersion, dispersion),
    radius: rand(size[0], size[1])
  };

});

force
  .nodes(data)
  .start();

root = data[0],
color = d3.scale.category10();

root.radius = 0;
root.fixed = true;

root.px = 250; //Center x
root.py = 275; //Center y

var nodes = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr({
    r: function(d) {
      return d.radius
    },
    cx: function(d) {
      return d.x
    },
    cy: function(d) {
      return d.y
    },
    fill: function(d, i) {
      return color(i % 3)
    }
  });

force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(data),
    i = 0,
    n = data.length;

  while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(data[i]));

  svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function collide(node) {
  var r = node.radius + 16,
    nx1 = node.x - r,
    nx2 = node.x + r,
    ny1 = node.y - r,
    ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
        y = node.y - quad.point.y,
        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
        r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**:

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var angle, offset, data,
  size = [8, 15],
  width = 500,
  color = d3.scale.category10(),
  height = 600,
  radius = 200,
  dispersion = 10,    
  svgContainer = d3.select('body').append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height).append("g");

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(0.05)
  .charge(function(d, i) {    
    return i ? -20 : -2000;
  })
  .distance(500)
  .size([width, height]);

data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
  angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  offset = Math.max(size[0], size[1]) + radius + dispersion;
  return {
    x: offset + Math.cos(angle) * radius + rand(-dispersion, dispersion),
    y: offset + Math.sin(angle) * radius + rand(-dispersion, dispersion),
    radius: rand(size[0], size[1])
  };

});

force
  .nodes(data)
  .start();

root = data[0],
color = d3.scale.category10();

root.radius = 0;
root.fixed = true;

root.px = 250; //Center x
root.py = 275; //Center y

var nodes = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr({
    r: function(d) {
      return d.radius
    },
    cx: function(d) {
      return d.x
    },
    cy: function(d) {
      return d.y
    },
    fill: function(d, i) {
      return color(i % 3)
    }
  });

var rotation = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  if(force.alpha()==0){
  if(!rotation)    
    rotation = Math.random() * 50;
  else
    rotation = rotation+1;
  svgContainer.attr("transform","rotate("+rotation+", "+(width/2)+","+(height/2)+")");
  }
  //force.theta(0.5);
},250);

force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(data),
    i = 0,
    n = data.length;

  while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(data[i]));

  svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function collide(node) {
  var r = node.radius + 16,
    nx1 = node.x - r,
    nx2 = node.x + r,
    ny1 = node.y - r,
    ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
        y = node.y - quad.point.y,
        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
        r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good One using quad :)

Comment: It looks really great! Thanks a lot! Is there a way set a little random distance between circles and also is it possible to make circles constantly but slowly moving somehow or rotating the whole thing like a galaxy ?

Comment: Added as short distance between nodes and also rotation of whole thing after the node positions are settled. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, something like this. But I realized that there will be icons and when rotating they will be upside down at some point. I tried with Cyril's example and got something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrychuba/ajnh877s/) but using of setInterval(function(){force.alpha(.1);},100); makes it load CPU a lot (as I need several of these galaxy circles on a page)

Comment: Please add it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this by force layout.
The idea is to keep all the links *display none* and center node *display none* none.
something like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .style("display", function (d) {
        return d.children ? "none" : ""; //ceneter node has children thus display will be none
    })
```

In such a case it will just look like the visualization you want to have.

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/vgmfcxcd/3/)

Hope this helps!